# How To Select Analyzer (or language) in Azure Search Suggester

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have some data in an Azure suggester with language specific characters í,ó,ú, etc.  Unless I search with those characters I don't get any results back. This would get solved if I was able to add an analyzer to the suggester (like lucene indexes have)

```
"suggesters": [
    {
        "name": "suggester",
        "searchMode": "analyzingInfixMatching",
        "sourceFields": [
            "Name"
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Suggesters are not supported on fields that use custom analyzers**. In some scenarios it makes sense to create another field analyzed with the standard analyzer (or a language analyzer) and use it for suggestions only.

We realize this is a limitation, please vote for this [feature](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/16079833-allow-suggestions-for-custom-analyzers) to help us prioritize.

Comment: Thanks... I don't get it.... are you saying I can make my "name" field searchable with a specific analyzer and the suggester is gonna pick on that? Or is it saying to create another field altogether?

Comment: Not sure I get what the solution you are proposing is.

Comment: I think the suggester is not support use custom analyzers. And you could wait the admin feedback.